# JavaScript works fine in any browser but Firefox?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

Ok this is my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function manageCart(task,item) {
var url = 'managecart.php';
var params = 'task=' + task + '&item=' + item;
var ajax = new Ajax.Updater(
          {success: ''},
          url,
          {method: 'get', parameters: params, onFailure: reportError});
}

function reportError(request) {
$F('cartResult') = "An error occurred";
}
```

And this is HTML

```
<p>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="manageCart('add',83)">Add to cart</a>
</p>
```

This script doesn't work in Firefox, I've ran a few Firefox JS debuggers but they displayed no errors. I'm not so good in JavaScript so please help me if you can :)
This script actually uses Prototype library if it will make things clearer.

Comment: Is the missing `"` in `onclick=manageCart('add',83)"` a typo?

Comment: Should you be passing a empty string to the success handler?

Comment: @w4rumy yes, it's a typo, it's not present in actual code

Comment: @Jonas there was an URL leading to "Added successfully" type of page but i don't need it so I removed it. Even if i'll return an original string it wouldn't work either

Comment: That {success: ''} thing is strange, to prevent possible problems, you should write { success: function () {} } or omit that completely if Ajax.Updater constructor allows it

Comment: Okay, so there is no success handler? How do you know the script does not work in FF? Because it does not fail? What if it succeeded? I think you should add some logging.

Comment: @Richard Did that, nothig changed

Comment: @Jonas A assume that there IS sucess handler, because it's originally led to "sucess page". I know this this script works because it passes item_id (83) and action (add) to the managecart.php file that writes item's id  into $_SESSION array and all added items then retrieved in the shopping cart. It works in ANY browser but Firefox. In case of FF, $_SESSION array, particularly $_SESSION['cart'] remains empty.

Comment: Try to change the event handler to onclick="manageCart('add',83); return false;" - it shouldn't change anything, just to be sure. Personally, I hate that javascript:void() syntax and inline event listeners, in big projects they cause only trouble.

Comment: @Richard nothing happened. If I only had an idea how to do things the other way, i'd probably tried it :(

Comment: I usually write something like <a href="managecart.php?task=add&item=83" class="jsAjaxUpdaterLink">... and then bind the updater to the class, reading href attribute and using it for the AJAX request. But this has probably nothing to do with your actual problem, it's just easier to debug.

Comment: When you say "This script doesn't work in Firefox" what doesn't work specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spent more time in FireBug and found the error.

Timestamp: 03.04.2013 10:36:38
Error: ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side
Source File: http://www.example.com/index.php
Line: 413, Column: 18
Source Code:

```
('cartResult') = "An error occurred";
```

Firefox desperately wanted for the statement to look like this:

```
('cartResult') == "An error occurred";
```

Comment: Ah yes the `$F()` method returns a string and not a reference to the value of the element - you are looking for `$('cartResult').update("An error occurred");`

Answer (score 1):

For this type of Ajax call do not use `Ajax.Updater` as that is designed to update a specific element with the contents of the ajax response. I believe that you want to just make a simple single ajax call so using `Ajax.Request` would be what you want to use.

Original Code using Ajax.Updater

```
var url = 'managecart.php';
var params = 'task=' + task + '&item=' + item;
var ajax = new Ajax.Updater(
      {success: ''},
      url,
      {method: 'get', parameters: params, onFailure: reportError});
```

Code using Ajax.Request

```
var url = 'managecart.php';
var params = 'task=' + task + '&item=' + item;
var ajax = new Ajax.Request(url,
     {
          method: 'get',
          parameters: params,
          onFailure: reportError,
          onSuccess: function(){
              console.log('It Worked');
          }
     });
```

I put a success handler in this call just to confirm that it worked for you - and it should output to your console. You can remove it or comment the `console.log()` when you are satisfied it works

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information, but the whole thing still doesn't work. I've found the problem